# Debugging not starting

Tags: php, sublimetext2, lamp, xdebug, sublimetext

**UPDATE:**

I've spent way too much time on this and have decided to ditch it and continue using the clunky NetBeans.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm having some difficulty getting xdebug to work with sublime text 2.

What I have done so far is install:

1. LAMP,
2. php5-xdebug
3. python2.6
4. sublime-text-2
5. sublimexdebug

If I then use sublime to open a php file and press shift+f8, the xdebug menu pops up from which I can `add/remove breakpoint` and also `start debugging`.

Some php:
[image: Some php]

Menu drops down when I press shift+f8:
[image: Menu drops down when I press shift+f8]

Debugging started:

[image]

In that image it says:

```
Xdebug: No URL defined in project settings file
```

Info.sublime-project contains:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/var/www"
        }
    ],

    "settings": {
        "xdebug": { "url": "http://localhost" }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the 3rd screenshot, I have started debugging and nothing happens, no errors, no browser window opens, nothing.  If I manually navigate to `localhost/info.php`, the page loads as normal.  If I manually add `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug` to the end of the url so `localhost/info.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug` and hit refresh on the browser, the page loads as normal and debugging still doesn't start.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE: Some info about ports:**

Before trying to start xdebug via sublime text 2

```
oshirowanen@ubuntu:~$ netstat -antp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp        0      0 90.190.20.220:54913     90.180.80.70:443        ESTABLISHED 2439/python     
tcp        0      0 90.190.20.220:51727     190.40.210.160:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        1      0 90.190.20.220:50967     90.180.90.20:80         CLOSE_WAIT  2349/ubuntu-geoip-p
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
oshirowanen@ubuntu:~$
```

After starting chromium manually and starting xdebug via sublime text 2

```
oshirowanen@ubuntu:~$ netstat -antp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2241/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59424         127.0.0.1:80            ESTABLISHED 2924/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43123         127.0.0.1:9000          ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          127.0.0.1:43123         ESTABLISHED 2903/sublime_text
tcp        0      0 90.190.20.220:40809     170.190.40.70:443       ESTABLISHED 2924/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 90.190.20.220:54913     90.180.80.70:443        ESTABLISHED 2439/python     
tcp        0      0 90.190.20.220:43900     170.190.70.90:443       ESTABLISHED 2924/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 90.190.20.220:35259     170.190.70.100:443      ESTABLISHED 2924/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59426         127.0.0.1:80            TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 90.190.20.220:37922     170.190.70.90:443       ESTABLISHED 2924/chromium-brows
tcp        1      0 90.190.20.220:50967     90.180.90.20:80         CLOSE_WAIT  2349/ubuntu-geoip-p
tcp        0      0 90.190.20.220:40847     170.190.40.60:80        ESTABLISHED 2924/chromium-brows
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59423         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:59424         ESTABLISHED -               
oshirowanen@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: There can be many things that you are "doing wrong". I would say the main problem is that you ask that way, because it leaves that much air  for general questions back like: What do you expect? Why do you say this is wrong? Who has told you that it should be different? Where is the reference that it should be different, please point to the part in the documentation that says it should work that way. Or is the impression right that you found some menu, clicked some entries, placed some breakpoints and *just blindly assumed that this works the way you feel*?

Comment: Even Sublime Text 2 can not read your mind, nor can I. So first of all I would say, you need to properly configure xdebug to get this running. That *starts* in your php.ini, see the documentation of xdebug here, it explains all this with pictures and in detail: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote - let us know if you've got some problem to understand how it works and tell us which part you've got a problem with.

Comment: @hakre, xdebug is definitely working.  I has been working on my computer for many many months using netbeans.  So now that I can say for sure that xdebug and php are working properly, what is the next step to figure out why sublime text 2 isn't working with xdebug?

Comment: Please provide a list of ethernet interfaces and ports your sublime2-text-process is listening on after you started it and/or started debugging with it. If you've setup xdebug in PHP correctly, then it can only be that you did not setup sublime correctly. Providing that list should help troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: @hakre, I honestly have no idea how to get that info.

Comment: well, take the keywords, use google, find some QA ;) http://serverfault.com/q/14429/69499 or `# netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN"` (however I think `-l` is already for listen, use `man` and `info` before using new commands)

Comment: I've added the requested info to the bottom of the question above.

Comment: The connection looks good: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          127.0.0.1:43123         ESTABLISHED 2903/sublime_text` - The URL is probably still missing, see [Issue #13 - Can't find URL in .sublime-project file](https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug/issues/13) - Have you configured it?

Comment: That's a good sign.  So if it is connecting, maybe I don't know how to step through the code?  I press shift+f8 and I don't see a step in option in the dropdown that appears.  Plus that small image in the question above about no url being defined

Comment: From what you pasted as configuration above, it's inside the `"settings"` property, but it should be in root. That should be causing you the URL problem.

Comment: I thought the settings were pointing to the root? i.e. `/var/www` and `http://localhost` ?  typing in `http://localhost` in the browser loads the index.php file located at `/var/www/index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

1. Check that Xdebug is running checking the information generated by the phpinfo command.
2. Enable remote debugging in the xdebug configuration (and verify again with the phpinfo command):

   xdebug.remote_enable=1
3. I don't use the xdebug setting in Sublime Text. I think it is not necessary.
4. Open the console in Sublime Text. Any problem is logged in the console. There are some problems in Ubuntu reported in the pulgin homepage.
5. I use a browser extension to activate or deactivate the debugging. In Chrome look for "Xdebug Helper for Chrome". You need to configure the cookie name as "sublime.xdebug".

Answer (score 0):

I use [Easy xDebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/) for firefox to kick start the debug session and that works a charm. You need to use "sublime.xdebug" for the idekey.

I presume that you've got some break points in there? Your screenshots imply that you do but make sure that you use the shift+f8 menu to add them.

Answer (score 0):

You have got a problem in your configuration, it is using the wrong syntax ([according to Issue #13](https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug/issues/13)):

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/var/www"
        }
    ],

    "settings": { <<<==== problem here
        "xdebug": { "url": "http://localhost" }
    }
}
```

Instead it should be:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/var/www"
        }
    ],

    "xdebug": 
    {
        "url": "http://localhost" 
    }        
}
```

This is probably also causing it not working.

Comment: I'm still getting a `XDebug: No URL defined in project settings file` when I start the debugging.  However, when I load the page I am trying to debug in chromium after having started the xdebug in sublime, sublime shortly displays a `xdebug: connected` message.  But I see no debug type info in the 2 small windows at the bottom of the sublime screen. and I see no step though/over/in type options when i press `shift+f8`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and submitted bug report here:

https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug/issues/58

However, it may be socket related bug in XDebug itself:

http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=141779#141779